# CPU Soft core on FPGA

Tags: fpga, verilog, vhdl, cpu

I need advice here.

One of my mid term hobby projects is to build an instruction set emulator of popular ISAs (e.g. ARM7) on a FPGA device. A lot of people have done this before.

My requirements are specific. I am looking for a development platform with SoC reference project and onboard peripheral support. Idea is to focus only on the CPU while the rest of the stuff comes from a reference project. It should be possible to compile and download an application in C into onboard volatile memory such as SDRAM have the soft core execute it.

What could be a possible development platform?

Comment: Take a look at opencores.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the [ARM7 softcore that exist on OpenCores](http://opencores.org/project,storm_core).

Or you can use an FPGA with an integrated ARM processor in it, the processor are not ARM7, but Cortex M3 in case of [MicoSemi SmartFusion and SmartFusion2](http://www.microsemi.com/products/fpga-soc/soc-fpgas), or [Xilinx Zynq FPGA](http://www.xilinx.com/content/xilinx/en/products/silicon-devices/soc/zynq-7000.html) that has a dual core Cortex A9, or [Altera's Cyclone V](http://www.altera.com/devices/fpga/cyclone-v-fpgas/hard-processor-system/cyv-soc-hps.html) which also has a dual core Cortex A9.

They all have development boards available with a free Software Development Environment to be used with their systems.

Comment: Thanks Morgan and Farhad. I have dowloaded AMBER from opencore and must evaluate next if it can be hosted on a spartan 3e dvice.